# Computing Edit Distance (feed_dict error)

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, levenshtein-distance

I've written some code in Tensorflow to compute the edit-distance between one string and a set of strings.  I can't figure out the error.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

# Create input data
test_string = ['foo']
ref_strings = ['food', 'bar']

def create_sparse_vec(word_list):
    num_words = len(word_list)
    indices = [[xi, 0, yi] for xi,x in enumerate(word_list) for yi,y in enumerate(x)]
    chars = list(''.join(word_list))
    return(tf.SparseTensor(indices, chars, [num_words,1,1]))


test_string_sparse = create_sparse_vec(test_string*len(ref_strings))
ref_string_sparse = create_sparse_vec(ref_strings)

sess.run(tf.edit_distance(test_string_sparse, ref_string_sparse, normalize=True))
```

This code works and when run, it produces the output:

```
array([[ 0.25],
       [ 1.  ]], dtype=float32)
```

But when I attempt to do this by feeding the sparse tensors in through sparse placeholders, I get an error.

```py
test_input = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
ref_input = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype=tf.string)

edit_distances = tf.edit_distance(test_input, ref_input, normalize=True)

feed_dict = {test_input: test_string_sparse,
             ref_input: ref_string_sparse}

sess.run(edit_distances, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-4e06de0b7af3>", line 1, in <module>
    sess.run(edit_distances, feed_dict=feed_dict)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 597, in _run
    for subfeed, subfeed_val in _feed_fn(feed, feed_val):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 558, in _feed_fn
    return feed_fn(feed, feed_val)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 268, in <lambda>
    [feed.indices, feed.values, feed.shape], feed_val)),

TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: The error likely comes from the value `test_string_parse` or `ref_string_parse`, can you provide the code for their creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** For the return type of `create_sparse_vec()`, use [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensorValue) instead of [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensor).

The problem here comes from the return type of `create_sparse_vec()`, which is [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensor), and is not understood as a feed *value* in the call to [`sess.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run).

When you feed a (dense) `tf.Tensor`, the expected value type is a NumPy array (or certain objects that can be converted to an array). When you feed a `tf.SparseTensor`, the expected value type is a [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensorValue), which is similar to a `tf.SparseTensor` but its `indices`, `values`, and `shape` properties are NumPy arrays (or certain objects that can be converted to arrays, like the lists in your example.

The following code should work:

```py
def create_sparse_vec(word_list):
    num_words = len(word_list)
    indices = [[xi, 0, yi] for xi,x in enumerate(word_list) for yi,y in enumerate(x)]
    chars = list(''.join(word_list))
    return tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, chars, [num_words,1,1])
```